# Python convert xml to list

Tags: python, xml, list

I have the following xml dataset:

```
<cnode desc="" name="xyz"> 
  <pnode name="word1"/> 
  <pnode name="word2"/>
  <pnode name="word3"/>
  ...
<cnode desc="" name="abc"> 
  <pnode name="word4"/> 
  <pnode name="word5"/>
  <pnode name="word6"/>
  ...
```

I want to get a list of all words after the name='xyz' and 'abc' respectively, e.g. xyz=[word1, word2, word3,...] and abc=[word4, word5, word6, ...]

I tried the follwing solution:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
xyz=[]
abc=[]

tree = etree.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root:
    words.append(child.findall(?!))
print(words)
```

But I can't figure out how to reference to the parent with name=xyz and then extract the words of the children.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Looks like you need a dictionary of lists : `{'xyz': ['word1', word2', 'word3'], 'abc': ['word4', word5', 'word6']}` Would you be able to continue if you obtain this kind of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly you should fix your demo xml there is a missing close quote

I would use xpath

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

xyzpnodes = root.xpath(".//cnode[@name='xyz']/pnode")
xyz = [p.attrib["name"] for p in xyzpnodes]

print xyz
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to find!! Thank you! and I included the missing quotes :)

Answer (score 1):

You can go for:

```
string = """
<nodes>
    <cnode desc="" name="xyz"> 
      <pnode name="word1"/> 
      <pnode name="word2"/>
      <pnode name="word3"/>
     </cnode>
     <cnode desc="" name="abc"> 
      <pnode name="word4"/> 
      <pnode name="word5"/>
      <pnode name="word6"/>
     </cnode>
</nodes>
 """

import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
xyz=[]
abc=[]

tree = etree.fromstring(string)

result = {}
for node in tree.findall('cnode'):
    name = node.get('name')
    if name not in result.items():
        result[name] = []

    for child in node.findall('pnode'):
        child_name = child.get('name')
        result[name].append(child_name)

print(result)
# {'xyz': ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'], 'abc': ['word4', 'word5', 'word6']}
```

This traverses the tree and child nodes and adds the corresponding values to the dict `result`.
It is even possible shorter with the help of `zip`:

```
result = dict(zip((cnode.get('name') for cnode in tree.findall('cnode')), \
            [[pnode.get('name') for pnode in cnode.findall('pnode')] \
                for cnode in tree.findall('cnode')]))
print(result)
```